# Dispatch GitHub Actions workflow from Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to trigger a GitHub Actions workflow from a Google Apps script, but I get `ReferenceError: Url is not defined`.

The following curl command works to trigger an example workflow:

```bash
curl -L -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/actions/workflows/$WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"main","inputs":{"email":"me@example.com"}}'
```

I tried to convert the curl command to its equivalent as a Google Apps Script:

```
  var ghToken = "GITHUB_TOKEN";
  var payload = {
    "ref": "main",
    inputs: {
      "email": "me@example.com"
    }
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer "+ghToken,
      'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  var response = Url.FetchApp.fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/REPO/OWNER/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW_ID/dispatches", options)
```

(`GITHUB_TOKEN`, `REPO`, `OWNER`, and `WORKFLOW_ID` are replaced with their actual values.)

However, when trying to run this script I get `ReferenceError: Url is not defined`, even though the curl command works with the same variables.

Comment: Typo - `Url.FetchApp` -> [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). This is nothing to do with curl or GHA (which as you say work fine)